# Mysql finding and combining min and max age

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying how to figure out the minimum and maximum age and show them horizontally. (as a single line)

Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT CONCAT(yu.first_name, ' ', yu.last_name) AS Youngest_person, 
TRUNCATE((DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), yu.date_of_birth)/365.25), 0) AS Age_youngest,

CONCAT(o.first_name, ' ', o.last_name) AS Oldest_person, 
TRUNCATE((DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), o.date_of_birth)/365.25), 0) AS Age_Oldest

FROM people yu, people o

WHERE yu.people_id = o.people_id

AND yu.date_of_birth = (SELECT MAX(date_of_birth) FROM people)
AND o.date_of_birth = (SELECT MIN(date_of_birth) FROM people)
```

I want the results:

Jessica | Chen | 2 | James | Franco | 148

Comment: please provide some simple demo data,and the result that you want.

Comment: @grocker I have updated with the result I want. As per demo data. I have the date_of_birth in regular for and the first name and last name. as per the question

Comment: Specify PRECISE MySQL version.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: When showing a query that doesn't work, then always tell us what happens. Do you get an error? Too many rows? Too few rows? Wrong values? (I suppose that your query just returns an empty result set?)

Comment: Thanks guys, my apologies, I am new, will make sure to be more clear in the future

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(yangest.first_name, ' ', yangest.last_name) AS Youngest_person, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, SYSDATE(), yangest.date_of_birth) AS Age_youngest,
       CONCAT(oldest.first_name, ' ', oldest.last_name) AS Oldest_person, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, SYSDATE(), oldest.date_of_birth) AS Age_oldest
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM people 
       ORDER BY date_of_birth DESC LIMIT 1 ) yangest
JOIN ( SELECT *
       FROM people 
       ORDER BY date_of_birth ASC LIMIT 1 ) oldest
```

For MySQL 8+ only:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_of_birth DESC) yangest,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_of_birth ASC) oldest
              FROM people )

SELECT CONCAT(yangest.first_name, ' ', yangest.last_name) AS Youngest_person, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, SYSDATE(), yangest.date_of_birth) AS Age_youngest,
       CONCAT(oldest.first_name, ' ', oldest.last_name) AS Oldest_person, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, SYSDATE(), oldest.date_of_birth) AS Age_oldest
FROM cte yangest
JOIN cte oldest
WHERE yangest.yangest = 1
  AND oldest.oldest = 1
```

Remember - if 2 or more people have the same minimal or maximal DOB then one random of them will be returned only (whereas your query will return all of them, with possible rows multiplying - do you need in this really?).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is this:

```
WHERE yu.people_id = o.people_id
```

Here you say that you only want a result if the youngest person happens to be the oldest person.

(Besides: We have stopped using comma-separated joins decades ago. They were made redundant in 1992, before MySQL was even released!)

Here is your query corrected:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(yu.first_name, ' ', yu.last_name) AS youngest_person, 
  TRUNCATE((DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), yu.date_of_birth)/365.25), 0) AS age_youngest,
  CONCAT(o.first_name, ' ', o.last_name) AS oldest_person, 
  TRUNCATE((DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), o.date_of_birth)/365.25), 0) AS age_oldest
FROM people yu
CROSS JOIN people o
WHERE yu.date_of_birth = (SELECT MAX(date_of_birth) FROM people)
  AND o.date_of_birth = (SELECT MIN(date_of_birth) FROM people)
ORDER BY yu.people_id, o.people_id;
```

In case of multiple people having the min or max age, you get them duplicated of course. E.g. with threee youngest people and five oldest people, you get 3 x 5 = 15 result rows. You may want to use `GROUP_CONCAT` instead, to get one rsult row with lists of all youngest and oldest.